# Populating SELECT options from database in SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, jquery-select2, simple-schema

Using SimpleSchema in Meteor with the AutoForm + Select2 plugins , i am trying to generate the Options for a Select field from the database.

The 'occupation' collection is published, and a collection 'Occupation' is defined in Meteor.

In SimpleSchema I have this:-

```
occupations: {
    type: [String],
    optional:true,
    label: 'Occupation',
    autoform:{
      type:"select2",
      placeholder: 'Comma spaced list of occupations',
      options: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('occupations');
        return Occupations.find({});

      }
    }
  },
```

But it does not return the collection results, and crashes the application without an error message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way to handle this is to supply the options list through a helper.

```
{{> afQuickField name='occupations' multiple=true tags=true options=listOccupations}}
```

Where `listOccupations` is a helper within the template containing the form.

```
Template.myForm.helpers({
  listOccupations: function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('occupations');
    return Occupations.find({}).fetch();
  }
});
```

And we remove the options object from the schena

```
occupations: {
    type: [String],
    optional:true,
    label: 'Occupation',
    autoform:{
      type:"select2",
      placeholder: 'Comma spaced list of occupations',
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, this approach:

```
autoform: {
  options: {
    var occupations  = [];

    Occupations.find().map(function(occ) {
       occupations.push(
         {label: occ.description, value: occ._id}
       );
    });

    return occupations;
  }
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: i did try something like this - but the async operation did not populate the select once it was drawn.

i will test using your code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm defining my collections schema in /lib/collections folder, and that is running on both server and client side. Given that, the console.log that I had was printing the correct values on server side and an empty array on client side. 
What I did was:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
Meteor.subscribe('service-categories-list', {
    onReady: function(){
        const serviceCategories = ServiceCategories.find({}).map(function(item, index) { 
            return {
                label: item.name, 
                value: item.slug
            };
        });
        Schema2._schema.type.autoform.options = serviceCategories;
    }
  })
}
```

I know that using the _schema is not a good idea, but I accept suggestions :)